# PHP email script not working/working intermittently

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**Problem**

I have a simple email script that sends Posted Form data to an email address. However i'm unsure to why it is not working E.I sending the data.

**Possible Reasons I Suspect**

1. My script is incorrectly written
2. My Ajax Post isn't working properly
3. Bootstrap is interfering with the whole thing.
4. My ISP/Hosting service is interfering with my email sending

**My Email Script**

```
<?php

    $name = $_POST['name']; 
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $tel = $_POST['tel'];   
    $enquiry = $_POST['enquiry'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $date = date('d/m/Y');
    $time = date('H:i:s');



        $headers = "From: Info@Columbus.com" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

        $emailbody = "<p>You have recieved a new message from the Contact Us form on your website.</p>

                    <p><strong><u>Contact Details</u></strong></p>
                    <p><strong>Name: </strong> {$name} </p>
                    <p><strong>Enquiry: </strong> {$enquiry} </p>
                    <p><strong>Email Address: </strong> {$email} </p>
                    <p><strong>Telephone: </strong> {$tel} </p>
                    <p><strong>Message: </strong> {$message} </p>


                      <br/>

                      <p>This message was sent from the IP Address: {$ipaddress} on {$date} at {$time}</p>";



        @mail("Hardcoreraver_2002@hotmail.com","New Enquiry",$emailbody,$headers);


?>
```

**My Form with Ajax PreventDefault() and BootStrap modal for confirmation**

```
 <div id="stylized" class="form2" >

      <form id="form2" method="POST" action="contactEmailScript.php" style="width: 500px; height: 400px; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 70px; float: left;">

        <label>Enquiry<span class="small">Type of Enquiry</span></label>

        <select id="enquiry" name="enquiry" required autofocus style="float:left" >
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="General">General</option>
          <option value="Change of Details">Change Of Details</option>
          <option value="Complaint">Complaint</option>
          <option value="Misc">Misc</option>
          <option value="Other">Other</option>
        </select>

        <label>Telephone<span class="small">Min. size 6 chars</span></label>
        <input type="tel" id="tel" name="tel"  placeholder="Tel. Number" style="float:left; width:195px;"/>

        <label>Email<span class="small">Add a valid Address</span></label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="johndoe@example.com" style="width:195px;" />

        <label style="padding-right:10px">Message<span class="required">*</span><span class="small">Additional Info</span></label>
        <textarea style="width: 200px;" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Your message must be greater than 20 characters" required data-minlength="20"></textarea>

        <button type="submit">Contact Us</button>
      </form>

      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
      <script>!window.jQuery && document.write(unescape('%3Cscript src="js/libs/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"%3E%3C/script%3E'))</script> 
      <script src="less-1.7.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
      <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
      <script src="bootbox.min.js"></script> 
      <script>

console.log ('before ajax');



 $('#form2').submit(function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
     bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function (result) {

         if (result) {
              console.log("user confirmed");

                 $.ajax({
                 type: 'POST',
                 url: 'contactEmailScript.php',
                 data: $("#form2").serialize(),
                 error: function () {
                     console.log('Ajax Error');}, //Debug Line
                 success: function (response) {
                     console.log('Ajax Success'); //Debug Line

                     $('.afterConfirmContact').css({
                         display: "inline",
                         height: 680,
                         width: 940
                     });

                       $('.beforeConfirmContact').css({
                         display: "none"

                     });

                     $('#form2').css({
                         display: "none"

                     });




 console.log("After CSS change");


                 }

             }); 
         }else{} 
     }); 
 }); 
    </script>
```

Any ideas would be great, i'm pretty confident that the code is written correctly.

**NB: *Strangely enough i have managed to send a few emails when testing, but only every half hour or so? So this leads me to think the isp or hosting company and blacklisted the email address or my ip? Is this possible?***

Comment: Yea great people downvote the question, that really helps me. If you say why i could rewrite it or learn what not to post etc!

Comment: I would first start by removing the `@` in `@mail`; that suppresses any errors you may get. Also, you're not checking whether or not an input has been filled or not (*not completely, anyway*), leaving your form open to people to enter blank data, which in turn may cause Emails being sent to Spam or ignored by your ISP/host since there stands to be no `From:` address. Your Email input doesn't contain `required` so that could be an issue as well.

Comment: You can also use this => http://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx to check if you've been blacklisted.

Comment: Thank you @Fred-ii- I will address all of the issues you have brought to my attention.

Comment: I don't appear to be black listed either, so thanks for the website link.

Comment: You're quite welcome.

Comment: Oh and @Fred-ii- I'm pretty sure i do have a from address set up in the headers section. "$headers = "From: Info@Columbus.com" . "\r\n";"

Comment: Yes I saw that after. I thought you'd want to use `$email = $_POST['email'];` for the `From:` instead of what you presently have.

Comment: No the posted email is the email address entered into the form by the user so they can be contacted.

Comment: Ok. Well, the way I do it is that I use the person's Email address as the `From:` so I can do a directly reply to. Maybe your ISP/host is noticing a lot of `From`'s coming from the same domain; being yours.

Comment: Yes @Fred-ii-, that does make more sense actually, i will change my to reflect your reasoning. My way was just was was i learnt off some website.

Comment: does this look about right? $headers = "From: '$email'" . "\r\n";

Comment: Close; use `$headers = 'From: ' . $email . "\r\n";` or `$headers = "From: $email" . "\r\n";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was either the isp or the email provider (hotmail) limiting the amount of emails send/received to one every 30 mins. Changed to my own paid email address and all problems have been resolved! Thanks to all the contributed and tried to help!